# antfill and antoutline no such file or directory xcode 12 (react-native-vector-icons)

Tags: xcode, react-native

Hi guys I need help for this error

> antoutline.ttf: No such file or directory
> antfill.ttf: No such file or directory

But I am not calling these 2

I have already added the fonts on my project and already added them on the `target->info->Fonts provided by the application`

```
React Native : 64
Xcode Version: 12
react-native-vector-icons:8.1
```

If you need more info please just comment it down so i can provide it. Thank you.

#EDIT
Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: same issue. how you fixed it